# How to code a zk roll-up in Solidity smart contracts?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, zksnark, zksync

Zksync is a protocol that recently enabled its layer-2 technology to directly admit layer-1 Solidity code for deploying on Zksync.

1. Aren't zero-knowledge proofs difficult to code using Solidity because they are mathematically intense?
2. What technical challenges do Solidity developers face when writing
   zk roll-ups?
3. Are there any popular packages that simplify zk coding for Solidity
   devs?
4. Could you provide an example of a simple zk circuit written in
   Solidity code?